# Reading all fragments of certain type from Apollo cache

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, graphql-js

> Is it possible to get all fragments of a certain type from the cache?

`readFragment` seems to be restricted to looking up only a single item by `id`. Looking at the data in cache I can see that it should be doable, but I can't figure out how to do this with public *API*.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean by fragment type?

Comment: When you define fragment you define it on certain GraphQL type. I would like to query all entries of Graphql type present in cache. Using `readFragment` you are forced to specify ID of the entry in cache. I am looking for something like `readAllFragments`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can find what you need by looking at [the source code for the apollo cache](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/144155c5b16dd36f052d8f7f9401bde51162b8b4/src/cache/core/cache.ts). It seems well documented. From a quick look you might be able to use the `extract`, assuming it gives you the information you need.

If you provide more information on the context / need this question is coming from, I'll be happy to improve this answer.